# CSS - overflow-y elements don't become scrollable

Tags: html, css, sass, less

I need to make y-axis scrollable block inside the left navbar. But I have faced with the issue - `overflow-y` element don't become scrollable.

How I need the content to look like: `div.left-infoboard` is the left block - 100% height of the page. At the top of this block there are some informational small `div`s. At the bottom there are too some blocks. After above `div`s there are scrollable block with a lot of elements. This block height need to fill all free space between above `div`s and bottom `div`s. 
 
 But this block, which I want to fill all free space between above blocks and below blocks is not scrollable and height exceeded 100%.

---

***Codepen sandbox (with all styles and html):*** https://codepen.io/car1ot/pen/rNerLbZ

---

***Short code:***

*CSS (scss) code:*

```
body {padding:0;margin:0;}

div.left-infoboard {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 290px;
    height: 100vh;

    div.bets {
        div.all-bets {
            div.bet-item {  height: 100px; }
        }
    }

    div.advanced {
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
}
```

*Html code:*

```
        <div class="left-infoboard">
            <div class="bets">
                 <!-- This is above section -->
                 ...

                 <!-- This is scrollable section, which I need 100% fit free space between -->
                <div class="all-bets">
                    <div class="bet-items">
                            <div class="bet-item">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="bet-item">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="bet-item">
                                ...
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- This is below section -->
            <div class="advanced">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your code is too large, you should only post snippets of what is not working. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have improved the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a flex layout and you want one of grand children to be vertically scrollable, you should set this style **on all of the children and grand children to that element**:

```
{
  display: flex; // use the flex layout
  flex-direction: column; // column layout
  flex: 1; // full height
  overflow: hidden; // don't expand the height when there is an overflowed child
}
```

[See the fixed version](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/zYqLwNB) | [Minimal example](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/xxVJaab?editors=1000)

Comment: No, your codepen style don't work properly. Still scrollable block dont shrinks and >100% of height.

Comment: @user14080657 sorry about that. i was on mobile and it was showing correct on that broswer. for cross broswer support, you need to use `overflow: hidden` on all elements to that child also. updated the answer.

Comment: @user14080657 also there was an `margin-right: -20px;` that was preventing the scrollbar to be visible. i removed that.